# How to return axios get value instead of [object Promise]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Axios get function always returning Promise even though I get the value in console.log

I use this code inside my vue js function

```
async encFolderID(_id){
        if(_id > 0){
            await axios.get(base_url+'Main/Process/FilesStorage/encFolderID/'+ _id).then(response => {
                return response.data.enc_id;
            })
        }
    },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `.then()`. Just `async` and `await`.

This is how you should use them:

```
async encFolderID(_id){
        if(_id > 0){
            const resp = await axios.get(base_url+'Main/Process/FilesStorage/encFolderID/'+ _id);
            return resp.data.enc_id
        } else ...
    },
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. can I use the function like this? :id="encFolderID(folder.id)", I'm trying to set an ID using the function.

Comment: Yes, but you still have to use `await` before the `encFolderID()`. sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `.then` while you marked `axios` with `await` keyword?
try this one. when using await you don't have to use `.then`

```
async encFolderID(_id){
        if(_id > 0){
            const res = await axios.get(base_url+'Main/Process/FilesStorage/encFolderID/'+ _id)
            return res.data.enc_id
        }
    },
```

Comment: hi is it possible to call a function using like this :id="encFolderID(folder.id)"?

Comment: you want to set the id using this function ? it should'nt be a problem if the function return successful data else you should do some error handling

Comment: Yes, but it still returning [object promise] when callling it on :id

Comment: you should use `await` right before the encFolderID function